# How to set some PDF reader's propertie via Webbrowser Control?

Tags: .net, pdf

First,I used Adobe Reader control and set some properties for hidden PDF Reader 's toolbar by this code.

```
            AxAcroPDF1.src = strFilename
            AxAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(False)
```

But now I don't want to use Adobe Reader Control .So I change to use Webbrowser instead.

```
           WebBrowser1.Navigate(strFilename)
```

When this program is run. The Webbrowser1 will display PDF with Toolbar.
How to hide a toolbar? What is possible?